# Passing pandas dataframe to keras.SimpleRNN layer

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I have a `df` which follows this structure:

```
Week_no     Feature_1       Feature_2       Feature_3       Feature_4       Feature_5       Target
1           32456           342             16473           73453732        6346            363
2           56352           435             75673           53456275        3534            254
3           27276           342             35362           23466425        2367            262
4           88437           327             75653           47567465        4737            625
5           84947           114             45732           45347367        3735            425
6           44744           434             22265           86534563        4845            353
```

I am trying to pass this data to `keras.SimpleRNN` to predict the `Target`. From multimple sources I've read that I should drop the time aspect of the `df`, then I split the data in to training, validation and test datasets.

`df.shape # (50, 6) after dropping the Week_no column`

Splitting the data:

```
n = len(inputs)
train_df = inputs[0:int(n*0.7)].drop(columns = ['Target'])
train_ans = inputs[0:int(n*0.7)]['Target']

val_df = inputs[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)].drop(columns = ['Target'])
val_ans = inputs[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]['Target']

test_df = inputs[int(n*0.9):].drop(columns = ['Target'])
test_ans = inputs[int(n*0.9):]['Target']
```

```
train_df.shape # (35, 5)
train_ans.shape # (35, )

val_df.shape # (10, 5)
test_df.shape # (5, 5)
```

I understand that the size is small, but this is for the sake of understanding how to pass pandas `dfs`.
From `keras` [documentation it states](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/simple_rnn/) and also, I've [checked this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992855/keras-how-should-i-prepare-input-data-for-rnn/62570576#62570576).

```
inputs: A 3D tensor, with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
```

So to my understanding to use this model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(5, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(5, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1)
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(train_df, train_ans, epochs=20,
                    validation_data=(val_df, val_ans))
```

Which currently produces an error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_75_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (35, 5)

I've tried reshaping my both `train` and `val` dataframes in to shapes of 3 dimensions but none of them worked and I've kept getting one of the two erros, one above or this:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_81_input to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (5, 5)

At this point I can't figure out the correct way of passing the data to the `SimpleRNN` keras layer and if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what your model should be doing. You can, for example, add a features dimension like this:

```
train_df = train_df[..., None]
```

So your data will have 5 timesteps and each timestep represents one of the features:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


inputs = pd.DataFrame(data={"Week_no": [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Feature_1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Feature_2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Feature_3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Feature_4": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Feature_5": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "Target": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

n = len(inputs)

train_df = inputs[0:int(n*0.7)].drop(columns = ['Target', 'Week_no'])
train_ans = inputs[0:int(n*0.7)]['Target']

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(5, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(5, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1)
])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(train_df.to_numpy()[..., None], train_ans, epochs=20)
```

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180881/how-would-one-use-a-rnn-when-predicting-temperature/71183956#71183956) to understand how you should work with dataframes and time series data.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what does `[..., None]` do after converting it to `np.array?`

Comment: It simply adds a new dimension to the end of the array. It is equivalent to  `array[:, :, None]`or `np.expand_dims(array, axis=-1)`